# Do particle beams shrink in radius?

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose we have some apparatus which emits a particle beam.

**How does the shape of the beam evolve over time?**

---

**Analysis:**

Suppose at the exit point of the emitter, the beam is of radius $r_0$ and particle density $n_0$ and all the particles in the beam have the same speed $v$.

Consider the cylindrical coordinate system with $z$-axis parallel to the direction of the beam and passing through it's center.

The current density created by the particles creates a magnetic field $\vec{B}=B(r,\theta,z)e_\theta$. There is presumably also an electric field $\vec{E}=f_1(r,z)e_r+f_2(r,z)e_z$.

let's neglect the electric field for the moment, because it seems hard to calculate. The resulting the Lorentz force is just the magnetic force term, and  is directed along $-u_r$, meaning the particles in the beam are pushed toward the center of the beam (this holds whether they are positively charged or negatively charged).

*Hence, the radius of the beam should shrink as $z$ increases!*

---

- Is it in fact the case that particle beams shrink in radius as we move further away from the source?
- How can we calculate the evolution of the radius $r(z)$? I tried doing so myself but the calculations became rather complicated and I wasn't sure which approximations I should be making.

Comment: The magnetic fields of moving charges are relativistic corrections to their electric fields, and they're therefore generally much smaller (unless there's other charges to cancel out the bulk of the electric field, as in a current-carrying wire). Neglecting the dominant contribution (which in this case is repulsive) is like the proverbial drunk looking for his keys under the lamppost because that's where the light is, except that he explicitly knows that he dropped them somewhere else ;-).

Comment: So ... you calculated the Lorentz force between the particles without accounting for the static electric force between them. Now, that kind of thing is allowed when you are talking about currents in wires because the wires remain neutral even with the current flowing through them, but this is a beam of charged particles propagating through a pretty good quality vacuum. The difference in the scale of the two effects is instructive. Beam scientists discuss "space charge" in this context.

Comment: @Emilio Since the magnetic field is a relativistic correction, this field will increase with velocity. What is it strength of this field for charges, moving near the speed of light?

Comment: @Holger This is covered in detail in introductory textbooks and in Wikipedia. If you have specific questions about those explanations, ask separately.